# Should an antecedent of "everyone" take "their" or "his" or "our" as its corresponding possessive pronoun?

Tags: gender-neutral, singular-they, antecedents, possessive-pronouns, indefinite-pronouns

I am still confused about how to use the word *everyone*.  I have this sentence on a test:

> 1. **Everyone** wants to do **their**  part.
> 2. **Everyone** wants to do   **his**  part.
> 3. **Everyone** wants to do  **our** part.

I think the answer is version with *their*.

Comment: What about *her*, *its*, *your*, or *my*? The question can't be answered without more information. If there isn't more information, then the question is invalid.

Comment: The problem that we cannot solve is that your test is not designed to teach you to produce "the right answer". It simply demands that you produce a single answer that matches what the designer of the test wanted you to say. Language is not something that often admits just one right answer, especially without further context, and this terrible test question is certainly open to more than one possible answer of varying suitability and acceptability depending on the context and register. Most people say *their*, and the OED give citations for this both ancient and modern—but Victorians protest.

Answer (score 4):

Your test is unfair, because there is no single answer that everyone would agree upon.

> **Everybody**, along with **everyone**, traditionally uses a singular pronoun of reference: *everybody must sign **his** own name*. Because
>   the use of *his* in this context is now perceived as sexist by some, a
>   second option became popular: *everybody must sign **his or her** own
>   name*. But *his or her* is often awkward, and many feel that the
>   plural simply makes more sense: *everybody must sign **their** own
>   name*. Although this violates what many consider standard, it is in
>   fact standard in British English and increasingly so in US English. In
>   some sentences, only *they* makes grammatical sense: *everybody agreed
>   to convict the defendant, and **they** voted unanimously*.
>   *(New Oxford American Dictionary)*

Comment: Everybody on the girl’s softball team had her own favorite batting strategy.

Answer (score 1):

The words **everyone** and **everybody** aren't about a specific person, so the (also gender-specific) **his part** is off. But the phrase is general, so **our part** is also not right.

I would say

> Everyone wants to do **their** part.

because it is common to use **their** in the singular and plural, just as **you** and **your** are used in both singular and plural.

Answer (score 0):

"our" is definitely wrong, as that is first person, and "everyone" is third person. Some might argue for "his", as each individual person is singular, but "their" has the advantage of being gender neutral. If you want to be precise and say that there is a set of people such that, given any person in that set, that person does the part of that person, rather than saying that each person does the part of the set as a whole, then you could say "his or her".